# Can we change #StackOverflowKnows to #StackExchangeKnows?

Tags: feature-request, twitter

[Since the end of 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/06/this-week-stackoverflowknows-about-infinity-internet-speak-and-password-storage/), the [Stack Overflow Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) has been tweeting out questions from around the network, using the hashtag #StackOverflowKnows ([see one of the latest examples](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1262494442000388104)). Users can submit questions by tweeting using the same hashtag. I'm a fan of it; while it's of course biased towards larger sites because of larger userbases and higher traffic, it's still nice to see the company promoting questions on the network, as opposed to Stack Overflow itself or the trilogy sites.

That said, I have a small suggestion to make: Can we change the hashtag the account uses from #StackOverflowKnows to #StackExchangeKnows? The majority of the content is from network sites, not stackoverflow.com or the company itself. Therefore, it seems a bit weird to promote questions from the network but implicitly kinda ignore that. It's a little thing, but little things have a tendency to build up and make a difference. I think this is a case where one of those little things could be fixed pretty easily.

Comment: Well, first the account name should be changed to Stack Exchange, otherwise it will be weird. But the way I see it, the tweets audience is the millions of Stack Overflow users, of which only a small percentage know what Stack Exchange is. For the vast majority, Stack Overflow is the site, the company, and everything else. :)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Yeah, both good points. I considered suggesting that [@StackExchange](https://twitter.com/StackExchange) be used for these - it's done that in the past, I know - but then of course there's the issue of reaching . . . not many people, even among those who use the network more than SO.

Answer (score 7):

Just an opinion from a guy who attempted to build a chat platform based on hash tags on Twitter:

**It's too late to do that.** If there are people engaging with this hashtag, then changing that hashtag will change the engagements.